$L^\infty$ is a Banach space; Le Gall
I'm reading a proof about the fact that $L^\infty(E,\mathcal A,\mu)$ is a Banach space in Le Gall's Measure theory, Probability and Stochastic processes.
I'm paraphrasing the proof. First we establish that $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is a norm and then we look at a Cauchy sequence $(f_n)$ in $L^\infty(E,\mathcal A,\mu)$. We show that $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty$ for every $m>n\geq 1$ and $x\in E\setminus N$, where $N$ is null. We realize that $(f_n(x))$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb R$ and converges to $g(x)$ (for $x\in N$, we simply put $g(x)=0$). Then $g(x)$ is measurable and if we take the limit as $m\to\infty$ in $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty$, we obtain $$\sup_{x\in E\setminus N}|f_n(x)-g(x)|\leq\sup_{m\in\{n+1,n+2,\ldots\}}\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty.\tag{1}$$I just don't understand how $(1)$ was obtained. In particular, the bound $\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty$ seems to depend on $m$, so as we take the limit in $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty$ as $m\to\infty$, what do we get? Any clarification around $(1)$ would be very appreciated.

It's really a few steps.  Here's a version which is written out more explicitly:
\begin{align*}
|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| &\le \|f_n - f_m\|_\infty & \forall m > n, x \in E \setminus N \\
|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| &\le \sup_{r > n} \|f_n - f_r\|_\infty & \forall m > n, x \in E \setminus N \\
|f_n(x) - g(x)| &\le \sup_{r > n} \|f_n - f_r\|_\infty & \forall x \in E \setminus N \\
\sup_{x \in E \setminus N} |f_n(x) - g(x)| &\le \sup_{r > n} \|f_n - f_r\|_\infty \\
\end{align*}
